# Create company in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, x++, dynamics-365

I have a unit-test in which I need to create a company and create/write data in that companys context. However it seems the company gets created, but I can't change my context.

i use this method to create the company:

```
private void CreateCompany(str companyName, str companyDisplayName, str countryRegion)
{
    var model = new OMNewLegalEntityViewModel();

    model.parmCompany(companyName);
    model.parmName(companyDisplayName);
    model.parmCountryRegion(countryRegion);

    model.createLegalEntity();
}
```

And i check if a company exists with this method:

```
public boolean CompanyExists(str company)
{
    CompanyInfo companyInfo;

    select firstonly * from companyInfo
        where companyInfo.DataArea == company;

    if(companyInfo)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //fallback
    return false;
}
```

The following is a shortened version of what is happening in my test method:

```
if(!this.CompanyExists('XXX'))
{
    this.CreateCompany('XXX','XXX','DEU');
    boolean companyCreated = this.CompanyExists('XXX');
    this.assertTrue(companyCreated);
}

changecompany('XXX')
{
    //do something
}
```

The `changecompany` throws an error that the company does not exist.

Am I missing something crucial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test your given code without problems using the newest update of Dynamics Operations installed. Maybe try updating your system if not already done and check if that helps.

**Version in use:**

Platform build: 7.0.5286.41360

Platform version: Update27

Product build: 10.0.107.20005

Product version: 10

Comment: thank you for taking your time, the image i developed on was pu24, i'll update to 27